# jQuery onfocusin/out and targetting input boxes, textarea and select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

I can't seem to get the below code to function properly to target the onfocusin for all input boxes, textareas and select elements, however, I do not want to target where input type='button'

```
    $('#content select, input[type='text'], #content textarea').focusin(function(e) {


    this.style.backgroundColor = '#colorcode'

    });
```

Comment: Double quote this `[type="text"]`

Comment: `$(':input:not([type="button"],button)', '#content').on('focus', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#content select, input[type="text"], #content textarea').focusin(function(e) {


    this.style.backgroundColor = '#colorcode'

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, you could also set the background-color with the css method, like:

```
 $('#content select, input[type="text"], #content textarea').focusin(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#colorcode");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
var inputs = $('input, textarea, select')
                .not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]');

$(inputs).focusin(function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#colorcode");
});
```